# How is a dividend amount that is a fraction of a penny handled?

Tags: dividends

If I own 15 shares of a stock that makes a cash dividend payment of 0.635/share for a total dividend payment of $9.525, who determines how the half-penny is handled?

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this situation

- For my brokerage account;
- From the issuing company (the issuing company usually states how fractional shares will be handled in a split/spinoff);
- From FINRA (http://www.finra.org); and
- I didn't even try to find an SEC rule.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a stock that is paying out dividends in fractions of a penny?

Comment: [Here is an example from Royal Bank of Canada](http://www.rbc.com/investorrelations/common-dividend-history.html) which paid out half-cents per share in 2005 and 2003.

Comment: That's not 5 thousandths of a penny, that is 5 thousandths of a dollar.

Comment: @Glen Yates, very true.

Comment: @Ben Miller, here are four of the literally hundreds of US traded companies with a market cap greater than US$ 100 MM that paid a fractional penny dividend that went _ex_ in November, 2018: ANHEUSER-BUSCH INBEV (BUD) 0.677/share; ELI LILLY AND COMPANY (LLY) 0.563/share; UNITED TECHNOLOGIES CORPORATION (UTX) 0.735/share; THE TJX COMPANIES, INC. (TJX) 0.195/share.

Answer (score 2):

I recently opened up a Robinhood account with a small amount of money. Due to their lack of commission fees I have been buying 1 share. They round the dividends up or down:

```
SCHZ paid a dividend of $.1286 per share. You were credited $0.13.
```

and

```
Number of shares 1  
Amount per share $0.0445
Total amount $0.04
```

I had one dividend that had the fractional penny equal to 5 and they rounded up, which was surprising since they will need to round up 50/100 times (given an odd number of shares), and round down only 49/100 times (not round at all 1/100), which seems to suggest they will lose money on the rounding. But I also received a dividend of 0.125 per share that they rounded down to $0.12 .  So they may alternate rounding the 0.005 up or down in order to avoid gaining or losing money the rounding.

Comment: the ...5 that was rounded up, was the resulting last digit *even*? [Bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) means rounding to even, precisely to avoid the asymmetry you spotted. You'll note that 0.125 -> 0.12 is rounding to even.

Comment: @AakashM I see a 0.045 that rounded to 0.05 . The only other "3rd digit is 5" dividend I have is 0.0257 -> 0.03.